# JAVA Loop in loop and multi result sets closing first result set

Tags: java, loops, resultset

I have a problem with this code:

```
im = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM imones");

        while (im.next()) {

            sask = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM saskaitos WHERE imone='" + im.getInt("id") + "'");
            while (sask.next()) {

                suma = suma + Integer.parseInt(sask.getString("suma"));

                kvit = stat3.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kvitai WHERE sask_nr='" + sask.getInt("sask_nr") + "'");
                while (kvit.next()) {
                    suma = suma - Integer.parseInt(kvit.getString("suma"));
                }
                kvit.close();

            }
            sask.close();

            //if (suma > 0) {
            imone = im.getString("pav");
            skola = suma;
            DefaultTableModel y = (DefaultTableModel) pagrindinis.visos_skolos_table.getModel();
            Vector rowData = new Vector();

            rowData.add(imone);
            rowData.add(skola);
            y.addRow(rowData);
            //}
        }

        im.close();
```

I get only one loop ( while (im.next()) ) because 'sask' query has no results and it closes 'im' resultset and multi Statements not helping. How can I get this code working? Thank you!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java language

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  You need to either ensure that `stat` and `stat2` are using different connections, or read all of the relevant data in `imones` into a Vector so  you can loop over it wouthout a database connection.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here but rather than nesting several loops in the Java, couldn't you just join the tables in the SQL?

Comment: imone table is company's table, saskaitos table is bill's table and kvitai table is cheque table. I need to get every company's dept amount, adding every bill's amount and subtract from them all payed cheques. I hope you understand my bad English. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested loops are not required, this can be done with one SQL statement that joins the table and sums the amounts. I obviously don't have all the column names at my disposal but you should be able to replace the names I've used with your own:

```
SELECT company.name,
       SUM(bill.amount) - SUM(cheque.amount) AS amount
FROM       imone     AS company
INNER JOIN saskaitos AS bill   ON company.id   = bill.imone
LEFT  JOIN kvitai    AS cheque ON bill.sask_nr = cheque.sask_nr
GROUP BY company.name;
```

Comment: That also has the advantage of letting the database deal with all the records -- a job it's made for.

Comment: Thank you man, I was forgot about how much SQL can. That solved my problem.

Comment: Well this not really solved the problem, because for example if I have 2 cheque's for one bill, example bill is 1000 and cheque's is 100 and 200 it returns 1700 not 700, it sums one bill two times because of two cheue's. How to fix it? Thank you!